# How to fix Asp.net-mvc website (using Culture and .resx files) changing language out of nowhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization, resources

We support a few languages, for which we have different traductions stored in the Properties of our website. Here are some of them: 
Resources.es.resx, Resources.fr.resx, Resources.resx (which contains english traductions).

Sometimes (like 3 times in the last year), our website becomes in french for ALL our english users.

We implemented some logging to try and understand what is happening. The last time the bug occured, what we observed is that when trying to get a sample string from our Resources.resx file, the result was from the Resources.fr.resx file. This was the case for all our users.

This is how we obtained that string:

```
string englishResource = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Add", new CultureInfo("en-ca", useUserOverride: false));
```

It's as if the Resources.resx was not found and the language defaulted to Resources.fr.resx.

When the website works properly, the returned string is always from Resources.resx, as expected.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it ?

EDIT: 
here is what we get for an english user when the website is displayed in french:

```
{
    SessionCulture: “en”,
    UserLanguages: [
        “en-US”,
        “en;q=0.9”,
        “fr;q=0.8",
        “es;q=0.7”,
        “ca;q=0.6",
        “it;q=0.5”
    ],
    LocalizationSystemLanguage: “en”,
    CurrentThreadCulture: “en-CA”,
    CurrentThreadUICulture: “en-CA”,
    EnglishResource: “Ajouter”,
    FrenchResource: “Ajouter”,
    SpanishResource: “Agregar”
}
```

the "EnglishResource" string should read "Add" instead of "Ajouter"